# How to fix Azure Cloud Shell error "MissingSubscriptionRegistration - The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'"

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-shell

I've just tried to use the fancy new Azure Cloud Shell announced at Build 2017 but I'm getting the following error (as a json message):

```
  {
    "error": {
        "code": "MissingSubscriptionRegistration",
        "message": "The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'"
    }
  }
```

I've googled this and found answers that suggest I need to register a resource provider with:

```
Register-AzureRmResourceProvider -ProviderNamespace Microsoft.Storage
```

or

```
azure provider register Microsoft.Storage
```

...but I'm too lazy to setup a command line session to Azure.

**How do I do this with the Azure portal?**

Answer (score 4):

I found the answer by poking around: The resource providers are hidden within Subscriptions -> {my subscription} -> Resource providers -> Microsoft.Storage -> Register.

The Cloud Shell should now work.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can also do this from the command line:

```
az provider list
az provider register --namespace Microsoft.Storage
```

Answer (score 0):

Relevent documentation for future reference is here --> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-common-deployment-errors#noregisteredproviderfound

This details how to resolve this through Azure portal, PowerShell, and Azure CLI.