# Unable to create storage for persisting account files in Azure Cloud Shell (CLI)

Tags: azure, command-line-interface, storage

I'm trying to setup [Azure CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/overview). The first step is to create a storage for account files. I'm using my `Developer Program Benefit` subscription.

[image: Persist account files dialog]

After I click "Create storage" I get an error:

```
Storage creation failed
Error:409
{"error":{"code":"MissingSubscriptionRegistration","message":"The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'. See https://aka.ms/rps-not-found for how to register subscriptions."}}
Can't create a storage account. Please try again.
```

How to resolve this issue?

[image: Storage creation failed]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you're getting this error is because `Microsoft.Storage` resource provider which manages Storage Account related resources and activities is not registered with your Azure Subscription.

To fix this, please run the following command:

```
azure provider register --namespace "Microsoft.Storage" --subscription "<your subscription name or id>"
```

To get the subscription name/id, please run the following command:

```
azure account list
```

For more details on why you're getting this error, please see this: [The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.DataFactory error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36200143/the-subscription-is-not-registered-to-use-namespace-microsoft-datafactory-error)

---

If you prefer GUI, then you can do it on the Azure portal too:

1. On the left pane click `More services` and then select `Subscriptions`
2. Select the subscription, in our case `Developer Program Benefit`
3. In the `Settings` area click `Resource providers`
4. Find `Microsoft.Storage` and click `Register`

Answer (score 1):

This same error with detailed solutions are provided in this post:

[How to fix Azure Cloud Shell error "MissingSubscriptionRegistration - The subscription is not registered to use namespace 'Microsoft.Storage'"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43907652/how-to-fix-azure-cloud-shell-error-missingsubscriptionregistration-the-subscr)